# Get values out of JSON (Map<String, Object>) with JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to get all the values (`linkID`,`text`,`options`) out of JSON example below (as a String result let's say) using JSONObject, JSONArray, getString() (org.json) library in Java? If yes, can someone please give an example.

```
"items": [
        {
            "linkID": "my/link1",
            "text": "Some text 1.",
            "options": [
                "yes",
                "no",
                "maybe",
                "always"
            ]
        },
        {
            "linkID": "my/link2",
            "text": "Some text 2.",
            "options": [
                "yes",
                "no",
                "maybe",
                "always"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution for example above. If there is a better one please tell.

```
JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject rec = items.getJSONObject(i);
            String linkID = rec.getString("linkID");
            System.out.println(linkID);
            String text = rec.getString("text");
            System.out.println(text);
            JSONArray options = rec.getJSONArray("options");
            System.out.println(options);
}
```

And can I get inner `code` that has value `61377` in example below if I have 2 keys with the same names `code` in JSON payload?

```
"code": {
           "code": "61377",
           "result": "ok"
           "info": "Some text"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can get the value of the inner field `code` by doing this,

```
jsonObject.optJSONObject("code").optString("code")
```

Where `jsonObject` is,

```
"code": {
           "code": "61377",
           "result": "ok"
           "info": "Some text"
},
```