# I've got some troubles fetching data from JSON array in Android studio

Tags: java, api, android-studio

I've got some troubles fetching data from JSON array in Android Studio

Part of code:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pnr_show);


    pnr_number=findViewById(R.id.pnr_number_show);
    train_name=findViewById(R.id.train_name);
    journey_date=findViewById(R.id.journey_date);
    chart=findViewById(R.id.chart);

    // For get the data from MainActivity.
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    String pnr= intent.getStringExtra("pnr_number");

    fetchData(pnr);
}

private void fetchData(String pnr) {
    String url ="https://pnr-status-indian-railway.p.rapidapi.com/rail/"+pnr;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .get()
            .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "pnr-status-indian-railway.p.rapidapi.com")
            .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "12ed1697f9mshb6e6505689ea560p13f681jsnf26a20cd4753")
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(PnrShow.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                String resp = response.body().string();
                PnrShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
                            String val1 = jsonObject.getString("train_number");
                            String val2 = jsonObject.getString("train_name");
                            String val3 = jsonObject.getString("passenger");
                            String val4 = jsonObject.getString("reservation_upto");
                            String val5 = jsonObject.optString("chart_status");
                            String val6 = jsonObject.getString("boarding_station");
                            String val7 = jsonObject.getString("passenger");
                            String val8 = jsonObject.optString("arrival_data");
                            String val9 = jsonObject.getString("departure_data");
                            pnr_number.setText("Passenger\t-\t"+val3);
                            train_name.setText("Departure_data"+"\t-\t"+ val9);
                            journey_date.setText("Journey\t-\t"+val8);
                            chart.setText("chart\t-\t-"+val6);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });



}
```

The main problem is that , I want data in synchronize way , screenshot mention below[In this I want to show data in particular manner like all passenger details line by line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnPOm.jpg)
[This is the image from where is fetch API data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKObc.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronize way"?

Comment: I mean , the data show separately ,   like  PNR Number: 1311545151 ,
Arrival Date = Date , 
Arrival Time = Time ,

Passenger :
Passenger Name 1 , Current Status ;
Passenger Name2 , current Status

Comment: Have a couple of `strings` as fields for each value you need to collect(the nine `string` values from your `onResponse`) and simply concatenate the data together from your JSON strings on every `onResponse` which you can use in your `setText()`s.

Comment: When I fetch string "departure_date" it contain two data and it show both data into array like                                                                                                                           {
"departure_date":"Sun, 07 Jun  06:25",
"departure_time":"Sun, 07 Jun  06:25"
}but I want  fetch both data separately like                                                                                                                                         departure_date : Sun,07 Jun 06:25,                                                   
departure_time : Sun,07 Jun 06:25

Comment: Try using `jsonObject.optJSONObject(value).optString(innervalue)` to get the innerfields(e.g `jsonObject.optJSONObject("departure_data").optString("departure_time")`). Source:[Get values out of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66366576/16653700)- T Shekhda.